# Powering unknown LCD and connecting to FFC connector?

Tags: lcd, zif

I recently took apart a dead LCD projector and found some tiny LCD displays inside, I have a total of three of these modules. Their model number is "Sharp G RLCDP0083CEZZ 952B18IK" and I wanted to drive them somehow. Either with an rPi or Arduino, just experimenting with them at first. Does anyone know how or where I could find a 32 pin ZIF flat-flex breakout board or how to drive these otherwise?

[image: Entire Module]
[image: Control Circuitry]

Comment: You'll need to find a datasheet first, and the datasheet is probably proprietary

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a more difficult-than-usual hack to drive those LCDs. It may be difficult to get good infos on them. But I did find a very good service manual for a projector that uses that LCD from
http://diagramas.diagramasde.com/otros/XG-NV6XU.pdf.

The service manual has the complete schematics for the projector. The key to understanding the operation of the LCD panels is identifying the LCD driver IC. I was able to find that in page 66; There's two CXA2112R LCD driver ICs per panel. The datasheets for that ICs are easy to find, and for your reference there's a picture below: [image]
Since the driver IC is analog, it tells you a little bit about what kind of project you are looking at: you'll need to generate the graphics signal yourself and feed it to the driver ICs, which will then feed it to the LCD panels.

It's a lot more work than using LCD modules that have a driver IC and video frame memory included in the module, since you need to generate the video signals with correct timings yourself.

Comment: Wow, Ok, thank you! I still have the control board so I may just reverse-engineer the controllers or find what's feeding them and control them from there.